# HPE Server Memory - Will any model be fine?

Tags: memory, hardware

I need to upgrade our HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen9 server with some more RAM. Before I buy anything I just wanted to confirm that it is okay to mix brands/models of memory as long as the type/frequency is the same? I know this is fine for desktop hardware, but just want to be sure it isn't going to cause an issue with server hardware.

This is the model of memory DIMMs that are installed currently:

[image: 1]

If I am correct in my assumption, is there anything else other than frequency and type (e.g. DDR4, ECC) that I need to ensure matches?

Comment: You should be fine as long as the RAM is compatible with your motherboard and the same type/frequency.

However, my preference has always been to have matching sets.

Answer (score 0):

HPE provide memory configuration guidelines for their servers: https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c05240460

- maximum supported speed is DDR4-2133 for v3 Xeons, DDR4-2400 for v4 Xeons
- you can use either all RDIMMs or all LRDIMMs, no mixing
- RDIMMs can be single-rank or dual-rank, LRDIMMs dual or quad (v4 supports octal as well)
- ECC is required

I'd recommend using only modules specifically suited for that server and CPU(s). Proper testing required for qualifying generic modules takes weeks.